# wrapping text in smartdiagram, bubble diagram type

Tags: smartdiagram

Consider the following minimal example:

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage{smartdiagram}
 \begin{document}
 \frame{
 \frametitle{frame title}
    \smartdiagramset{
        bubble center node font = \small,
        bubble node font = \scriptsize,
 %      bubble node size =2.5cm, 
 %      distance center/other bubbles = 0.5cm,
        satellite text width=0.5cm,
        planet text width=1.75cm}
    \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
    very long text,
    short text,
    long text,
    a much longer text,
    text text text text text,
    text text text text text text text text text
    }
 }
 \end{document}
```

Why is the `satellite text width` option not working? I would like to have the text being wrapped or hyphenated. According to the `smartdiagram` manual this option is possible for the `bubble diagram`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is misleading. The options listed are not all common to bubble and constellation diagrams. Rather, the ones with names like 'satellite...' only apply to constellations.

This should probably be reported as a bug in the documentation.

To set a text width for bubble diagrams, you can use `tikzset` to modify the `bubble node` and `bubble center node` styles.

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
  \frame{
    \frametitle{frame title}
    \smartdiagramset{
      bubble center node font = \small,
      bubble node font = \scriptsize,
      bubble center node size =2.5cm,
      bubble node size =1.5cm,
    }
    \tikzset{
      bubble node/.append style={
        text width=1.5cm,
        align=center}
    }
    \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
      very long text,
      short text,
      long text,
      a much longer text,
      text text text text text,
      text text text text text text text text text
    }
  }
\end{document}
```

[image: bubbles]

Comment: You beat me for seconds this time!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Sorry...

Comment: Is it possible to create tree diagrams easily with smartdiagram? like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/v53dD.png

Comment: @skan Please don't repeatedly ping me to keep asking the same thing. Wouldn't it be a whole lot easier and quicker for you to ***look in the manual***?