# No newline in smartdiagram

Tags: line-breaking, smartdiagram

i'm a bit confused by the smartdiagram package: I can't make any \newline, and it does not do it by itself ([see here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/pnpxsfykhwgp)), as have seen in other cases of me using it before, or in [this other tex stackexchange post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254974/wrapping-text-in-smartdiagram-bubble-diagram-type). Now i am confused and hope someone here might help me. Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: I don't know what you've tried, but if you want automatic wrapping of the text, I guess you need to set the `text width`, as is done in the other question you refer to.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem! Still i would love to know, why i can't put any  \newline in there, which would make formatting it more easy...

Comment: Use `\\ ` instead of `\newline` (still with `text width` set).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Would you put an answer together such that this question can be marked as answered?

Comment: @LJKS As mentioned in the question I linked to above, you can also set just `align=center` (or `left`/`right`), and use `\\ ` where you want line breaks.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. well, then I flag it as possible duplicate…